# self-referencing ForeignKey with default value None

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

How can I set a default value on a self-referencing ForeignKey field in a django Model?

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
   id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
   name = models.CharField('')
   master = models.ForeignKey('self', default=None)
```

When saving without informing the master the error below occurs

```
ValueError: save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object master
```

Comment: maybe add a `null=True`?

Comment: @dan-klasson it's works. Thanks